# How to implement concurrency control for data insertion and querying in CnosDB?

Tags: cnosdb

I've encountered a challenge while using a time-series database, where there might be issues with data insertion and querying under high concurrency. I'm concerned about potential conflicts when multiple users attempt to insert or query data simultaneously, potentially leading to inconsistencies or data loss.

I'm interested in learning about best practices or techniques for implementing concurrency control to ensure stability and consistency in a time-series database under high loads.